# cannot use -fallow-argument-mismatch as #cgo FFLAGS:

Tags: go, fortran, cgo

I am in the process of updating to a new version of gfortran (9.4 to 11.3) for a go application that uses cgo to execute fortran code.  I am getting a rank mismatch error:

```bash
somdec.f90:507:36:

  111 |           call respir(co2los,2,SRFC,som1c,som1ci,s11c2,resp, &
      |                                    2
......
  507 |           call respir(co2los,1,SRFC,som3c,som3ci,s3c2,resp, &
      |                                    1
Error: Rank mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (rank-1 and scalar)
```

This is a common occurrence as fortran developers used to have optional args and now don't, fixing this error/feature deletion will be a pain as this spans across a vast number of functions.  Places online tell me to use `-fallow-argument-mismatch` flag as an -fflag in gfortran, however go does not support the use of this flag

my cgo config:

```golang
package main

// #cgo LDFLAGS: -lm
// #cgo CFLAGS: -Wstringop-overflow=0
// #cgo FFLAGS: -fallow-argument-mismatch
import "C"

etc...
```

and I get the error:

```bash
go build myapp: invalid flag in #cgo FFLAGS: -fallow-argument-mismatch
```

Unless there is a good way to fix/mitigate the black box that fortran is, my only option is to use this seemingly deprecated fortran flag, does cgo explicitly disable this flag?

I've also tried setting these as environment variables, but to no avail

```bash
export FFLAGS=-fallow-argument-mismatch
export FCFLAGS=-fallow-argument-mismatch
```

It's frustrating that this is a common thing that happens to fortran developers with a deprecated flag being the only option and with little/unclear documentation on fixing this error.

Comment: "This is a common occurrence as fortran developers used to have optional args and now don't" - I really don't follow what you mean by this. Optional arguments came into the language in 1990, so your logic seems the wrong way around. -fallow-argument-mismatch is a flag to permit the compiler to process code that has *never* been valid Fortran. Around about gcc 10 (not sure exactly) gfortran started requiring that the code was valid in this way unless specified otherwise by the flag. IMO this is a good thing - it stops broken code being processed.

Comment: I fully agree with the -fallow-argument-mismatch not being a good flag, Is there a way to fix this issue of mismatched arguments without using the flag?

Comment: Can you use -std=legacy? If so does that "fix" it? In many ways worse but it's the only other compiler flag I can think of  - if possible fixing the code is by far the best option

Comment: I agree with Ian. Also, this is not a depreceted flag. The check is quite new.  cgo might not have added the support for this flag yet. But I do not know how it works.